# Cannot remove startup items

Tags: macos, startup

I cannot remove the WD items from the startup list. The delete button is not active (greyed out).

[image: Screenshot Startup items]

I looked for entries in:

- /Library/LaunchDaemons/
- /Library/LaunchAgents/
- ~/Library/LaunchAgents
- /Library/StartupItems

But without luck, no WD items found. Any ideas where I have to look?

Comment: What does the warning message at right say?

Comment: Something like items cannot be found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(All Users)*-login items are stored in the file /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginitems.plist. Normal user login items are saved to ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginitems.plist.

Some WD apps add login or startup items to /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginitems.plist and /Library/Preferences/loginwindow.plist.

The WD installer apps (e.g. WD Access for Mac) usually provide an uninstall feature which removes the respective app as well as login items or other installed files. The plist files itself won't get deleted though even if it was created by the WD installer.

If the uninstaller doesn't remove unwanted items you can do it yourself by either editing the global plist file or removing the complete plist.

A default file /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginitems.plist or ../loginwindow.plist **doesn't** exist (in Sierra) but may have been created and modified by other installers. You can get the content by executing `sudo defaults read /path/to/plist` in the Terminal.app window.